# Android: Should Java and Kotlin have the same versions if used in the same project?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jvm

I have an old Java android project which uses Java6 compiler that I want to extend , but I like new "parts" to be written in Kotlin(I have no xp in Kotlin). So, basically since Java code emits Java 6 compatible byte code should I configure my Kotlin compiler to emit Java6 compatible byte code as well? So, I mean in general should there be a match between Java and Kotlin versions? Because in my imagination JVM cannot execute(at least cannot execute correctly) program which parts are compiled to different bytecode

Comment: a jvm version N knows how to run bytecode targeted for a previous jvm version. If you don't use any removed api you can run java 6 on java 16.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they should match. There are certain functions that the compiler will complain about if you don't. A Kotlin library that was compiled for Java 6 can run fine in a Java 8 app, but if a project targets Java 8, but doesn't configure the Kotlin code to compile to Java 8, the compiler gets stuck on some types of higher-order functions and SAM conversions, in my experience.

Kotlin in an Android project by default compiles to Java-6 compatible bytecode, so if you are sticking with Java 6, you don't have to do anything. If you want to use Java 8 features, you add this to the `android` block in `app/build.gradle`:

```groovy
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
```

I recommend using Java 8 because various notes in the javadocs of the Jetpack libraries indicate that they plan to eventually require Java 8.